# Как установить позицию создаваемого окна?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Здравствуйте. В ExtJs 3.1 создаю окно

```
new Ext.Window(... ... ... определения окна... . .)
```

При создании, оно появляется сразу в центре. Вопрос:
**Как** изменить позицию его появления? Т.е. чтобы оно было не в центре а, например, 20 пикселей сверху и 50 слева?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У окна есть config свойства [x](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-x) и [y](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-y). То есть как-то так:

```
new Ext.Window({x: 50, y: 20})
```

Comment: Да, получилось. Спасибо.